# How to submit an list when one of the list item is selected

Tags: javascript, list, search, autocomplete, dropdown

hello i am creating a search bar that has auto complete feature can someone tell how to **auto submit** when one of the option is selected

some other possible solutions are  autosubmit when the input field contains $
{i will add a $ swmbol in each of the array}

you can check the whole program on codepen by clicking here

https://codepen.io/simplyrajatgupta/pen/wvmXPJv

here is the codes

```js
let suggestions = [
    "Channel",
    "CodingLab",
    "CodingNepal",
    "YouTube",
    "YouTuber",
    "YouTube Channel",
    "Blogger",
    "Bollywood",
    "Vlogger",
    "Vechiles",
    "Facebook",
    "Freelancer",
    "Facebook Page",
    "Designer",
    "Developer",
    "Web Designer",
    "Web Developer",
    "Login Form in HTML & CSS",
    "How to learn HTML & CSS",
    "How to learn JavaScript",
    "How to become Freelancer",
    "How to become Web Designer",
    "How to start Gaming Channel",
    "How to start YouTube Channel",
    "What does HTML stands for?",
    "What does CSS stands for?",
];



















// getting all required elements
const searchWrapper = document.querySelector(".search-input");
const inputBox = searchWrapper.querySelector("input");
const suggBox = searchWrapper.querySelector(".autocom-box");
const icon = searchWrapper.querySelector(".icon");
let linkTag = searchWrapper.querySelector("a");
let webLink;

// if user press any key and release
inputBox.onkeyup = (e)=>{
    let userData = e.target.value; //user enetered data
    let emptyArray = [];
    if(userData){
        icon.onclick = ()=>{
            webLink = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${userData}`;
            linkTag.setAttribute("href", webLink);
            linkTag.click();
        }
        emptyArray = suggestions.filter((data)=>{
            //filtering array value and user characters to lowercase and return only those words which are start with user enetered chars
            return data.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(userData.toLocaleLowerCase());
        });
        emptyArray = emptyArray.map((data)=>{
            // passing return data inside li tag
            return data = `<li>${data}</li>`;
        });
        searchWrapper.classList.add("active"); //show autocomplete box
        showSuggestions(emptyArray);
        let allList = suggBox.querySelectorAll("li");
        for (let i = 0; i < allList.length; i++) {
            //adding onclick attribute in all li tag
            allList[i].setAttribute("onclick", "select(this)");
        }
    }else{
        searchWrapper.classList.remove("active"); //hide autocomplete box
    }
}

function select(element){
    let selectData = element.textContent;
    inputBox.value = selectData;
    icon.onclick = ()=>{
        webLink = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${selectData}`;
        linkTag.setAttribute("href", webLink);
        linkTag.click();
    }
    searchWrapper.classList.remove("active");
}

function showSuggestions(list){
    let listData;
    if(!list.length){
        userValue = inputBox.value;
        listData = `<li>${userValue}</li>`;
    }else{
      listData = list.join('');
    }
    suggBox.innerHTML = listData;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body{
  background: #644bff;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

::selection{
  color: #fff;
  background: #664AFF;
}

.wrapper{
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 150px auto;
}

.wrapper .search-input{
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}

.search-input input{
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 60px 0 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.search-input.active input{
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.search-input .autocom-box{
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  max-height: 280px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.search-input.active .autocom-box{
  padding: 10px 8px;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.autocom-box li{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: default;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.search-input.active .autocom-box li{
  display: block;
}
.autocom-box li:hover{
  background: #1bb361;
  color: white;
}

.search-input .icon{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 45px;
 ;
  width: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #1a74f2;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.search-input
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Autocomplete Search Box | CodingNepal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
            
            <form action="https://www.google.com/search?q=">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="search-input">
        <a href="" target="_blank" hidden></a>
        <input type="text" id="ra"placeholder="Enter question or chapter...">
        <div class="autocom-box">
          <!-- here list are inserted from javascript -->
        </div>
        <div class="icon" id="ca"type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>

    <script src="js/suggestions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
      var input = document.getElementById("ra");
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementsByClassName("ca").click();
  }
});
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For starters ```document.getElementsByClassName("ca").click();```

Should be 
```getElementById("ca").click()```

Answer (score 0):

Instead write code for clicking search button, you can just call `window.open('http://url-goes-here.com')`.

```
inputBox.onkeydown = (e) => {
  let firstSuggestion = suggestions.filter(el => 
el.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase()))[0];
  
  if((e.keyCode == 13) && firstSuggestion)
      e.preventDefault();
      window.open(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${firstSuggestion}`)
    }
}
```

This function make input that matched with first suggestion auto-submitted when enter key pressed. If you wanna use this function, make sure you delete another function that also record enter key in input.

`.onkeydown` make any key pressed in inputBox will be 'record'. If the key pressed is enter (enter keycode = 13) and first suggestion exist (not null), so you will be redirect to google url + first suggestion query.

`firstSuggestion` in here, defined as filtered `suggestion` list, which only include suggestion that contains character of your search query.

Comment: @Ant Genube since i knoew only very basic of the javascript; can you please modify the script and provide it to me

Comment: @Rajat Gupta; just add my code to JS section in your codepen.io

Comment: if you may wanna do autocomplete instantly, you can check [jquery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)